# Ray Tracing in Haskell

Tags: performance, haskell, raytracing

I have worked in a (very basic) *ray tracing* software in the past in C++.
Now want to create an advanced system (CSG, radiosity, etc) from scratch.

I find interesting to implement it in Haskell, because I'm learning functional programming too.

Performance is a very important fact in *ray tracing* algorithms. A Haskell program is in general slower than a C++ program. How much? It depends on the context.

Considerating this context (i.e. a *potentially* very complex RT) is it  viable to work in Haskell?

Comment: Yes, it is viable and there are many ray tracers in Haskell already (both on Hackage and elsewhere).  You should make your question much more precise if you want a good answer.

Comment: Yes, there exist high performing haskell ray tracers. It is a legitimate language choice. However, if you're a beginner to Haskell and already know C++, you're going to write better/faster C++ than Haskell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It might be worth checking out Repa for flat parallelism. You can get pretty good performance if you know what you're doing, but to get great performance it can sometimes require reading and inspecting the core output to see why things aren't being unboxed.

It depends, though. If you're writing C code for absolute performance, you're most likely not going to *beat* C with Repa, because the alias analysis doesn't seem to be very good at the moment.
But unless you're hand-fusing your C code into one monolithic function, I suspect the benefits you get from fusion and the 'free parallelism' in Repa might help it compete.

http://code.ouroborus.net/gloss/gloss-head/gloss-examples/raster/Ray/

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jBd9c1gAqWs

And don't use lists. If you don't want to use Repa, I suggest you use Data.Vector.Unboxed.

Answer (score 3):

I'm relatively new to Haskell as well. I just a bit ago committed a quaternion fractal ray tracer to bitbucket written in Haskell at https://bitbucket.org/ratzes/hray/src.

The code isn't perfect, but its rather small and yielded the images in the samples folder.

I used the Repa library (Nice tutorial on Repa [here](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Numeric_Haskell%3a_A_Repa_Tutorial)) which in my opinion was perfect for my ray tracing program. It allowed me to specify a function to calculate a "hit" for a particular photon and then it automatically parallelized that function over each of the photons.

Admittedly, fractal ray tracing is easier than generic ray tracing because you can sample at any point on the "photons" path to ask if it collides. Also, didn't implement anything advanced like radiosity or caustics, so I can't comment on how well things like those scale.